# my import is not found in the google ads api while i have the dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, google-ads-api

i am trying to run this example from the google ads api doc : https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/samples/get-invoices?hl=fr .

when i try to compile i have this error : java: package com.google.ads.googleads.examples.utils does not exist

i have added the maven dependency for google ads api in version 25.0.0 (the last one) but the includes from the part example of the dependency are still not found.